# Getting approximate location when Location on phone is turned off

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, location-services

I'm just wondering if it's possible to get an approximate location when the Location services on the phone is turned off.

For example, when I turn off my Location and open Google Maps, it shows my location in about a 2km radius. Then I can set start and end points for navigation.

In my own app, how can I do something similar? i.e. show their locality rather than just a map of India

Comment: please check this - http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html, you can get the location details and use that lat and lang to display.

Comment: Using the link provided by Natarajan does not work when Location on phone is turned off

Comment: as far as I know, Google maps will keep track of the last known location before someone turns off the location and this location would be shown when I open the Maps again without the location being on again. This will change to show the actual location only when user turns location ON again.